# Embedded camera not working - Camera reserved by another app error

Tags: windows-10, camera, integrated-camera

Since one 1 week, my camera is not working on my Lenovo W541 (Windows 10). Any way to kill the process using it? Rebooting does not fix it. Here is the error if I write down "Camera" in the Windows search: [image]

Comment: I had a similar problem. I fixed it by installing a different driver. There was an update from the manufacturer that caused problems. I deleted the device in device manager and the driver too, rebooted let windows install the camera using its own drivers, and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To see what devices are *allowed* to use your camera, do the following.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *priv* and select *Privacy* settings.

[image: Privacy settings for Camera]

- Select `Camera`.
- There are two lists of applications, *Microsft Store apps* [once know as "Metro apps"] and *desktop apps*. **Disable (set to `Off`) any application you do not need.** Note that some settings may be disabled by Group Policies or through third-party software. For example, [ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) and [similar privacy applications](https://alternativeto.net/software/shutup10/) may "gray out" some settings, so you may also need to change settings in the privacy application.

This should allow your desired process to access the camera.

If this does *not* fix the issue, or if you find applications listed that you do not recognize, then check for spyware with a thorough scan, perhaps using an alternate antimalware suite. Someone could be watching you...